# IN SQL Server, is the sys.partitions.partition_number = sys.partition_range_values.boundary_id for the same table and partition?

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

There are several tables used to track and control partitioned tables in SQL Server.  Two of these seem to have columns with the same meaning and values but with different names.

`sys.partitions.partition_number` has a column `partition_number`.
`sys.partition_range_values` has a column `boundary_id`

These seem to be the same values, for a given partition scheme.  FWIW, partition number is also returned by the special function `$PARTITION` as in

`$PARTITION.<partition function>(value)`

This also seems to correspond to the `boundary_id` column in the row in the `sys.partition_range_values` table containing the matching value.

FWIW from Microsoft articles:

> boundary_id   int ID (1-based ordinal) of the boundary value tuple, with left-most boundary starting at an ID of 1.
>
> partition_number  int Is a 1-based partition number within the owning index or heap. For non-partitioned tables and indexes, the value of this column is 1.

Can anyone confirm that these the two columns of these tables do indeed hold the same values for a given partitioning function and scheme?

I would like an official reference that my search skills seem unable to find.

Comment: Did you have a read of [sys.partitions (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-partitions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [sys.partition_range_values (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-partition-range-values-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: @Larnu Yes, indeed!  Hence the question.  Neither article refers to the other and the descriptions are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, it does not.**

- `sys.partition_range_values` is foreign-keyed to `sys.partition_functions` over the `function_id` column, which is unique in the DB.
- You can connect this with the table via `sys.partition_schemes`, which has a `function_id` column. This also has a `data_space_id` column, which has a many-to-many mapping to `sys.data_spaces` via `sys.destination_data_spaces`.
- And as far as I can tell, `destination_data_spaces.destination_id` is the same as `sys.partitions.partition_number`.

Complicated, but if you have used partition functions and schemes you will see how it maps out to the way they are used.

Comment: Yeah all familiar to me.  So the basic takeaway is that prv boundaries relate to functions but since they are independent of schemes (many functions can be used with one scheme), the boundaries and partition numbers vary independently of each other.  Make sense?

Comment: Yeah I think that's right. Basically the table uses a partition *scheme*, the scheme uses a partition *function*, the function has *boundary values*, that's basically the idea